# Does anyone know how I could implement "tags" in my Android app similarly to how StackOverflow allows you to add tags?

Tags: android, tags

I have researched this extensively but the only thing I have found for Android is EditTag which only uses preset tags. I want the user to be able to type in a box, and then when they hit space, it creates the last word as a tag. The idea is then for these tags to be searchable. Does anyone know if such a library exists or how I can get started implementing these?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips

Comment: are you looking for a library or to implement this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at this library `https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup`

I'm using it and it is very simple. You can do things like this:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]